# SQL mostrando registros se apenas atenderem condições diferentes do usual

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, firebird

Tenho uma situação um pouco diferente, tentei diferentes condições mas nenhum trouxe o resultado desejado.

Minha necessidade é a seguinte:

Tenho uma base contendo autores de livros e suas respectivas obras.

Preciso criar uma consulta que traga apenas os autores que tiveram o primeiro livro publicado a partir de **1919**.

Segue script para criação das tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTOR (
    ID INT,
    NOME VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE LIVROS (
    ID INT,
    ID_AUTOR INT,
    TITULO VARCHAR(255),
    ANO INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_AUTOR) REFERENCES AUTOR (ID)
);
```

Segue script para inserção dos dados amostragem:

```
INSERT INTO AUTOR (ID, NOME) VALUES (1, 'MACHADO DE ASSIS');
INSERT INTO AUTOR (ID, NOME) VALUES (2, 'EUCLIDES DA CUNHA');
INSERT INTO AUTOR (ID, NOME) VALUES (3, 'CLARICE LISPECTOR');
INSERT INTO AUTOR (ID, NOME) VALUES (4, 'JOSÉ DE ALENCAR');
INSERT INTO AUTOR (ID, NOME) VALUES (5, 'MONTEIRO LOBATO');
INSERT INTO AUTOR (ID, NOME) VALUES (6, 'CECÍLIA MEIRELES');

INSERT INTO LIVROS (ID, ID_AUTOR, TITULO, ANO) VALUES (1, 5, 'O Saci-Pererê: resultado de um inquérito', 1918);
INSERT INTO LIVROS (ID, ID_AUTOR, TITULO, ANO) VALUES (2, 5, 'O Picapau Amarelo', 1939);
INSERT INTO LIVROS (ID, ID_AUTOR, TITULO, ANO) VALUES (3, 6, 'Espectros', 1919);
INSERT INTO LIVROS (ID, ID_AUTOR, TITULO, ANO) VALUES (4, 3, 'Perto do Coração Selvagem', 1944);
```

A consulta correta deve trazer o seguinte resultado:

**Result**

```
| id(autor) |       nome(autor)      |
|------------------------------------|
|    6      |    CECÍLIA MEIRELES    |  
|    3      |    CLARICE LISPECTOR   |
```

Monteiro Lobato não virá na consulta pois tem uma publicação anterior ao ano de 1919.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_livros WHERE ano >= 1919` Isso já irá te trazer todos os livros de 1919 pra cima, se precisar APENAS que sejam de 1919 mude a condição `>=` para `==`

Comment: Pesquise por NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a cláusula IN:

```
SELECT * FROM AUTOR WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID_AUTOR FROM LIVROS GROUP BY ID_AUTOR HAVING MIN(ANO) >= 1919);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para entender mais sobre JOINS, você pode ler [Cláusulas INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN e RIGHT JOIN no SQL Server](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930) ou [JOINS em SQL](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/joins-em-sql).
Recomendo ler também: [MIN(Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) e [SELECT – GROUP BY – Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

No seu caso, a QUERY(Select) ficaria assim:

```
SELECT AUTOR.ID,AUTOR.NOME FROM AUTOR
INNER JOIN LIVROS ON
AUTOR.ID=LIVROS.ID_AUTOR
GROUP BY AUTOR.NOME,AUTOR.ID
HAVING MIN(LIVROS.ANO)>=1919;
```